# Simple statement to calculate the number of days between two 8 Digit dates using PHP?

Tags: php, date, time

Please let me construct a statement to calculate the number of days between two variables that have the format: 20211024. This is of course the year, then month, then day in a single eight digit variable.

Answer (score 1):

By using the [DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class?

```
$d = new DateTime('20211024');
var_dump($d);

$d2 = new DateTime('20211014');
var_dump($d2);

echo $d->diff($d2)->format('%R%a days');
```

That example code gives the output:

```
object(DateTime)#7 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2021-10-24 00:00:00.000000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(3) "UTC"
}
object(DateTime)#8 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2021-10-14 00:00:00.000000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(3) "UTC"
}
-10 days
```

Example [fiddle](https://phpize.online/?phpses=51fe33f9a6ebbbd400f0d34c5331ff74&sqlses=null&php_version=php8&sql_version=mysql57)

Comment: Thanks so much. I'm inexperienced and I'm trying to add this into some existing SELECT statement, but I get a php syntax error when I try the following:

                                                $query1="
                            SELECT
                                COUNT(ID) as iNumShipped,
                                avg(DateTime(EMAIL)->diff(DateTime(substr(DATETIME,0,8)))->format('%R%a')) as iAveDays
                            FROM........

Comment: Cannot use PHP in SQL, because SQL does not know PHP. There is no mention of SQL in the question?

Comment: Sorry, you're correct. Ideally it would be great to be able to do this within the SQL statement.

But if not, I tried this in the  php section:
$d = new DateTime(EMAIL);

$d2 = new DateTime(substr(DATETIME,0,8));

echo $d->diff($d2)->format('%R%a days');

But this causes a blank page...

Comment: The carry-over from the SQL to PHP is likely the error. `substr` on `DATETIME` is likely invalid in the PHP code. Inversely, PHP does not know SQL. Other than that, where do those time values come from? ... seems that would be something from the table to calc an average? ... anyway, see code lines 17-25 in [this fiddle](https://phpize.online/?phpses=bd4ecebbab4993fbc206452262d28031&sqlses=null&php_version=php8&sql_version=mysql57)

Comment: The DATETIME and EMAIL have come from a table lookup. I also tried creating $DateTime and $Email from these lookups, but the result is the same: a blank page.

Comment: Check the server log to see what errors are present. Blank page implies error, which could be parse error, syntax error, etc.